# How to toggle checkbox in jQuery mobile listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, jquery-mobile-listview

I got stuck with toggling `checkboxes` within a `listview` in jQuery Mobile. The checkboxes can not be toggled when I click on the checkbox itself, but it works when I click on the row using the following code-snippet:

*jQuery snippet*

```
$('#components a.ui-btn').click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
});
```

*HTML snippet*

```
<div data-role="content">
  <ul id="components" data-role="listview">
    <li>
      <a class="ui-btn">
        <input name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" type="checkbox"/>
        Some random text
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rautJ/1/) to demonstrate my problem. Furthermore, I added a screenshot below illustrating the problem. The checkbox is even not clickable, if I do not use any jQuery code, so I expect the checkbox is not toggling twice. I would appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: First off, having a checkbox inside an anchor tag does not make sense. Are you just looking for a list of checkboxes http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rautJ/2/, or do you need both a checkbox and an anchor? http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Xf8QT/

Comment: @ezanker Your first fiddle is the way to go. However, I would like to have the look and feel of a list view. Means, I need the same margin/padding, without the rounded corners etc. Do you know the jQuery class(es) to get the same look?

Comment: You can add data-role="none", you can also use a vertical control group. Both examples are in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rautJ/7/

Comment: I've added `class="ui-btn" style="margin-bottom: 0;"` to all `label`'s to get the expected look and feel. Please post your comment as answer and I will except it. `data-role="none"` does not work for me, because I have more than a checkbox and plain text in a row.

Comment: @ezanker Please post your jsFiddle example as answer and I will except it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/rautJ/7/)**

Make sure the checkboxes are not inside an anchor tag. You can apply data-role="none" to stop jQM from styling the checkboxes:

```
<ul id="components" data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" type="checkbox" data-role="none" />Some random text #1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" data-inline="true" data-role="none" />Some random text #2</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A second option is a vertical controlgroup:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>Vertical:</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a" />
    <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b" />
    <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c" />
    <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
</fieldset>
```